# EConvertError error raised while installing Fonts in Shree-Lipi Nxt

Tags: windows, fonts, languagetool

I have installed Shree Lipi Nxt version 8.1.8682.19818, a typing tool . But the problem is when I try to install Shree-Lipi ex Fonts of any language ,it gives following error.
[image]

[image]

But this error does not show if I install Unicode fonts.
I am using Windows 10 pro x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution, Here it is:-

This problem is due to the "fonts" folder being in so many directories,simply Copy and put it out directly to Local disk (D/E). and then select it as source folder in shreelipi font manager. and the problem will be fixed.

Comment: Thanks. We just need to copy a particular language font folder to any drive (D or E) or even to a new folder and choose it from "Select Source Directory" . then it will work.